# Trying to make a simple recursion exercise

Tags: c++, c, function, recursion

Hi  im trying to create this function :
**double harmonicSum(int n) that calculates and returns the sum 1 + ½ + 1/3 + ... + 1/n**

*This is my code*

```
double harmonicSum(int n)
{
  if(n==1) return 1;
  return (1.0/n) + (1.0/(harmonicSum(n-1)));
}
```

It doesnt work properly . If i call harmonicSum(1) or harmonicSum(2) it works , but with harmonicSum(3) no .

**CORRECT CODE**

```
double harmonicSum(int n){
if(n==1) return 1;
return (1.0/n) + harmonicSum(n-1);
```

}

Comment: See "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: why are you using a recursive algorithm for this? Also what is `f6'?

Comment: Sorry , edit :)
I'm just practicing in doing recursive functions

Comment: When you say it doesn't work what happens that is wrong?

Comment: I am afraid you made a mistake in the algorithm, because it will calculate `1/n+1/(1/(n-1)+1/(1/n-2)....)

Comment: Great , i have corrected and now works

Comment: yeap) that looks like it should work

Comment: Please make sure that the question is properly retired: either delete it (as not useful for future searchers) or post your answer and accept it.

Comment: Which of the two tagged languages are you _actually_ using?

Comment: why didn't you accept the answer below?

Answer (score 0):

```
simply try like below
double hermonic(int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return 1 ;
    else
        return ( float )  1/n + hermonic(n - 1) ;
}
```